Horizontal pulsating line HTML
I am trying to do some pulsating lines using HMTL and CSS. However, I can't make a line pulsate when this is set to be fully horizontal. I am unfamiliar with web development and I recon something is wrong with my understanding of how the "gradient-mask" seen in the snippet below works. Does anyone have any idea how this can be fixed?
Here is what I have that is functional. However when I try to change the line "y2" parameter to make it horizontal. It does not work.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<title>Pulsating Line</title>
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.son1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  
}
 .son2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.son3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

@keyframes slideMask {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.mask-rect {
  animation: slideMask 3s ease infinite;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="parent">

    <div class="son1">
    <svg width="100%"  fill = "none" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <line x1="0" y1="30" x2="100%" y2="0" stroke="#2660fb" stroke-width="7"  />
    </svg>
  </div> 
  <div class="son3">
    <svg width="100%"  fill = "none" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <line x1="0" y1="30" x2="100%" y2="0" stroke="gray" stroke-width="7"  />
    </svg>
  </div>  

  
  <div class="son2">
    <svg width="100%">
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="gradient">
                <stop offset="0" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0" />
                <stop offset="0.8" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="1" />
                <stop offset="0.8" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="1" />
            </linearGradient>
            <mask id="gradient-mask" fill="none" >
                <rect class="mask-rect" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#gradient)" />
            </mask>
        </defs>
        <line x1="0" y1="30" x2="100%" y2="0" stroke="#75c3fc" stroke-width="7" mask="url(#gradient-mask)" />
    </svg>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>




Please read SVG Line with Gradient Stroke Won't Display if vertical or horizontal

Something like this? Animate gradient pulse along SVG path
